# Importing a configuration file gives mach-o-linker

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Its very strange, i have a `.h` file with many const and variables .

I have tWo classes that use him, hence import him:

`classA` , and `classB`  with : ( `#import "configurations.h"` )

Now another new class that i have added, `C` , came in , and when i am trying to do the same with him, import the configuration file - i get a `mach-o-linker` error .

Check this out : even if the new class `C` is empty(!) i cant add that configuration file and get the same error . i have tried also with new classes , and its the same .
I could only add it then , to A B and now, no more importing !

**EDIT**

Ok, i now get it , first its not happen in class A and B because: `A.m` and `B.mm` hence i can import them both with that .h file .

Than the problem is probably because i dont use `extern` with my consts in the .h file ?
(i have tried extern and still got errors) , i create somehow 2 copies of consts from .h :
How i define them in .h file ? just like that :

```
const int wordSize=8;
const int numOfWords=8;
```

Whay am i missing here ?

(there is some other class D ,that import A B C if its matter )

Comment: One more detail , classes A B where dragged into xcode, and linked with binary(in Xcode) , and C was created IN xcode itself ...

Comment: make sure that there is no circular import happening

Comment: thanks checked that, its not .. i am pretty sure it has to be with the fact that i have imported that file along with the 2 others ,and every new .m that i create within the project-does not get that .h file

Comment: where are you adding `#import` to? If to `.h`, try moving it to `.m` files. Also, how are your consts and vars in `configurations.h` defined? Could you paste some sample..

Comment: i have a clue-check my new edit maybe you could help . thanks .

Comment: Are those `int`s actually constant or do you want to change them?  If the former then `const`; if the latter then you'll need `extern` and then actually define them somewhere.

Comment: they are just a consts, no change. but still i can't import that file and the problem is still here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h file is for declarations
.m file is for definitions
It means no "=" signs in .h, no method implementations. If you have constant:

configurations.h

```
extern const int wordSize;
extern NSString * const someStringConst;
```

configurations.m

```
const int wordSize = 8;
NSString * const someStringConst = @"someStringConst";
```

If you import your 
configurations.h

```
const int wordSize = 8;
```

from multiple files, compiler generates _wordSize symbol for every file that imported configurations.h
Linker for sure cannot resolve these duplicated symbols - so the best approach is to get rid  of definitions in your .h file using `extern` declaration like i've shown above.

Comment: thanks i know that way with the .m file, i wanted to use only a .h file if possible. one more thing, what about global static that i have? how would i implement it with that way ?

Comment: Either you use #define WORD_SIZE 8 or you use both .h and .m files. Your task can't be done just with global var in .h file - it cannot be resolved. It relates not only to int - every non-extern variable in .h file will force to linker error if .h is imported from multiple files

Comment: i think #define is what i need because of many other reasons , but how can i define arrays with values ?

Comment: if you want NSArray you can simply `#define myArr (@[@"str1",@"str2,@"str3"])`  If you defined strings before like `#define str1 (@"str1")` u can `#define myArr (@[str1])` . However, cause of much reasons using both .h and .m is MUCH better approach. Actually try to explain yourself, why do you need exactly only .h file? I cannot imagine such needs.

Comment: thanks. thats because when i import that file into another file, than want to use one of the consts , and set it as a size of an array , for example : array[wordSize]; , than complier dont let me . in that case you want to use define . check the first answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988122/static-const-int-not-good-enough-for-array-size